# Acessing a mercurial repository on a shared host over SSH

Tags: ssh, unix, shared-hosting, mercurial

I have a shared hosting account with SSH access. I have set up a virtual Python installation and have copies of the system folders in `$HOME`: `~/bin, ~/lib` ...

I have installed mercurial through easy_install and everything is groovy: The `hg` executable sits at `~/bin/hg` and my `$PATH` knows of this. I can create and commit to repositories fine on the server.

However, when I try to clone my repo to my laptop via SSH I get an error that `hg` can't be found.

```
$ hg clone ssh://myuser@server/hg/foobar
remote: jailshell: hg: command not found
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

How to I tell mercurial (or SSH or jailshell) where to look for the executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Mercurial where exactly the `hg` command is on the remote machine by using the `--remotecmd` option to `hg clone`. See `hg help clone`.

You can also set it in your `~/.hgrc` or the `.hg/hgrc` of a specific repo clone. I think it belongs in the `[ui]` section.

Comment: in .hg/hgrc:
[ui]
remotecmd = /home/username/bin/hg